# pull access denied for "aaaaa" repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'

Tags: docker, ubuntu, gitlab

After cloning a project from Gitlab on ubuntu, I tried to run it through docker, I opened a terminal, got to the directory where the .yml file was and wrote down:

I was greeted with this message:

> The image for the service you're trying to recreate has been removed.
>   If you continue, volume data could be lost. Consider backing up your
>   data before continuing.

Continue with the new image?

```
I pressed y.
```

Then for a few seconds, I got:

```
Pulling "name of the module here"
```

Then I was greeted with this message:

```
ERROR: pull access denied for "name of the module here", the repository does not exist or may require 'docker login'
pedroesteves@pedro:~/Desktop/project$
```

Any help would be very appreciated. I already looked to some similar posts but none was able to help me.

Comment: which image are you trying to pull? can it belong to some private registry

Comment: all the images im trying to pull belong to the private gitlab repo. But i have access to it via git, i already cloned it

Comment: So I guess i need to perform some sync with gitlab and docker in order for docker to be able to pull the images, however even if my guess is right I dont know how to that. A set of instructions or commands would be very appreciated.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

You can pull image from a private registry, but You will get an error on the new version of Docker related to certificated,  during pull image on the client side.

First, you to modify docker daemon file on the client side

create the file if not exist

```
/etc/docker/daemon.json
```

Add the following

```
{ "insecure-registries":["gitlab.my-site.com:5000"] }
```

Then you are good to go

```
   docker login gitlab.my-site.com:5000
```

Comment: do i need to add the port 5000 ?

Comment: yes if its registry using port 5000 or not if its not the part of URL

Comment: going to try that! thanks, ill post feedback in a few minutes.

Comment: :( i stil get: Error response from daemon: Get https://gitlab.companyname.com/v2/: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority after creating the daemon.json file with { "insecure-registries":["gitlab.companyname.com"] }

Comment: did your restart docker on client side?

Comment: What command should i write in the terminal to do that ? Is it sudo docker restart ?

Comment: yes or may service docker restart or supervisorctl restart docker

Comment: I did that but i still get the x509. It asks me for a username and password, it is refering to the docker (username and pass) ,right ?

Comment: i still get "Error response from daemon: Get https://gitlab.companyname.com/v2/: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority"

Comment: how you setup registry?